# Data science for brain signal processing

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science-model

I want to create a model which analyzes brain signals and detect if an action is performed (e.g., move hand, move leg). I've seen several studies on the subject, however I'm not sure if the topic is extremely complex to dive into without knowledge in the domain.

If anyone worked on this topic previously, do you have any recommended literature and sensory equipment for data reading (e.g., EMOTIV)